# what is the function bound to in node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Like below code in node.js file:

```
function test() {
    console.log(typeof this)
}
```

the code result is `object`

I know that if the code run in browser, this function is bound to default window object. Obviously the result is **object**

but what is the function bound to in node.js file?

thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s the global object just like in the browser, also accessible through `global`.

Answer (score 0):

When `strict mode` is not used, `this` will be a global object shared by all modules.

`node js1.js` should print true in the following example:

```
// js1.js
const logT2 = require("./js2").logT2;

function logT1() {
  return this;
}
const thisInT1 = logT1();
const thisInT2 = logT2();
console.log(thisInT1 === thisInT2 && typeof thisInT1 === "object");
```

```
// js2.js
function logT2() {
  return this;
}

exports.logT2 = logT2;
```